# How to rewrite URL in MVC 5 for dynamically populated pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

I'm just creating a database driven web application. For this purpose I created a Controller :

```
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    private StoreDB db = new StoreDB();

    public ActionResult LoadOneColumnPageContent(string pageId)
    {
        List<tbl_UserControl> tbl_UserControls = db.tbl_UserControl.Where(it => it.Active == true && it.PageId == pageId).OrderBy(it => it.Id).ToList();
        return View(tbl_UserControls);
    }
    public ActionResult LoadFullWidthPageContent(int id)
    {
        List<tbl_UserControl> tbl_UserControls = db.tbl_UserControl.Where(it => it.Id == id).ToList();
        return View(tbl_UserControls);
    }
}
```

Which populates the Model

```
public partial class tbl_UserControl
{
    private int? _priority;

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string MainText { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ButtonText { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string UrlLink { get; set; }

    public string PageId { get; set; }

    public string TypeId { get; set; }
}
```

And displays the data in the View :

```
    @using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
    @model IEnumerable<newSiteMVC.Models.tbl_UserControl>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "LoadOneColumnPageContent";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    @*<%--------------------- Top Banner with moving image ---------------------%>*@

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Shared/_PageTopBanner.cshtml", Model)

    @*<%--------------------- Main page content ---------------------%>*@

    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(it => it.TypeId != "NewsFeed" && it.PageId == @Request.QueryString["pageId"]))
    {
        if ( item.TypeId != "TopBanner" && item.TypeId != "TwoColumn" && item.TypeId != "VideoPod")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImageUrl))
            {
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Shared/_OneColumnComponent.cshtml", item)
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Shared/_OneColumnWithImageComponent.cshtml", item)
            }
        }
    }
    @if (@Request.QueryString["pageId"] == "InTheNews")
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Shared/_OneColumnWithLinkComponent.cshtml", Model)

    }

    @if (@Request.QueryString["pageId"] == "ContactUs")
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Shared/_FullWidthContactPage.cshtml", Model)

    }

    @if (@Request.QueryString["pageId"] == "ShoppingCart")
                {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Pages/Shared/_TwoColumnComponent.cshtml", Model)

    }

    @*<%--------------------- Moving Background Image ---------------------%>*@

    @Html.Partial("_MovingBackgroundImage")
```

At this very moment the web application shows the two following url patterns :

```
http://localhost:63294/Pages/LoadFullWidthPageContent/54
```

Or

```
http://localhost:63294/Pages/LoadOneColumnPageContent?pageId=ContactUs
http://localhost:63294/Pages/LoadOneColumnPageContent?pageId=AboutUs
```

I was wondering if there is any way to make the URL more SEO friendly, taking into account that all pages are loaded through the same controller and action (different data is displayed for each pageId) besides two pages that use different action in the same controller. I would like the links to look like

```
 www.somewebsite.com/News/54
 www.somewebsite.com/ContactUs 
 www.somewebsite.com/AboutUs
```

Is it even possible and if so any ideas how I could implement it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not complete answer but trying to give you a hint, As I worked on similar kind of routes make page more SEO friendly. If it could help you can make use of.

```
         var route1 = routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Products",
             url: "Clothes/{param1}/{param2}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Clothes", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

Here Param1 and Param2 are optional , you could add anything there.

Like in your case, you can add

www.somewebsite.com/content/News/54

```
         var route1 = routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Page",
             url: "Content/{param1}/{param2}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "LoadOneColumnPageContent", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked `UrlParameter.Optional`